# In D6, $sr^as= r^{6 - a}s^2$?

Tags: group-theory

The title is claimed in my book without further proof, so I suppose it should be obvious, but I don't see it. It is equivalent to $sr^a = r^{6 - a}s = (sr^{a})^{-1}$, but I don't see how that is true. $sr^asr^a = r^5sr^{a - 1}sr^{a}$, but how is this equal to the identity?

$D6$ is the dihedral group of order 6 with the rotations $e, r, s$ and multiplications thereof which are completely determined by $r^6 = e, s^2 = e$ and $r^5s = sr$. It is from groups and symmetry by Armstrong.

Comment: What are $r$ and $s$? You talk about your book, but most of us don't have it, and none of us know what it is.

Comment: Please state your defining relations for the group.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown sorry, I thought that was standard notation, I'll edit it in my post.

Comment: So $sr=r^{-1}s$. An easy induction gives $sr^k=r^{-k}s$ etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual group presentation of $D_6$ is $$\langle s, r \mid srs^{-1} = r^{-1}, r^6=s^2=1\rangle$$

So $s=s^{-1}$; then $$sr^as = (srs^{-1})^a = (r^{-1})^a = r^{-a} = r^{6-a} s^2$$

That first step $sr^as = (srs^{-1})^a$ is a very useful one to know. It follows inductively, using as an example $$(srs^{-1})(srs^{-1}) = sr(s^{-1}s)rs^{-1} = sr^2s^{-1}$$